# Delay sending mails to boost page load time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `Product#create` method I have something like

```
ProductNotificationMailer.notify_product(n.email).deliver
```

Which fires off if the product gets saved. Now thing is before the above gets fired off, there are bunch of logics and calculations happening which delays the confirmation page load time. Is there a way to make sure the next page loads first and the mail delivery can happen later or in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to look into background workers. [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/), [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) are some popular ones.

Here's a great [RailsCast demonstrating Sidekiq](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

```
class NotificationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(n_id)
    n = N.find(n_id)
    ProductNotificationMailer.notify_product(n.email).deliver 
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what `n` was in your example, so I just went with it. Now where you do the work, you can replace it with:

```
NotificationWorker.perform_async(n.id)
```

The reason you don't pass full object `n` as an argument, is because the arguments will be serialized, and it's easier/faster to serialize just the integer id.

Once the jobs is stored, you have a second process running in the background that will do the work, freeing up your web process to immediately go back to rendering the response.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to do inside of rails? I believe I cant install redis on the production server nor can run two instances (rails and redis) at the same time.

Comment: @psharma, DelayedJob won't require the extra redis server, but you're still going to need a separate process for the background worker to handle jobs outside the normal request/response cycle of your Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed jobs will do this:

[Here is the github page.](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

[and here is a railscast on setting it up.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised)